# golang: array sharing between slices

Tags: go

[This](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#append) explains append function for slices.

As it says, append returns the updated slice.

So does it mean that newly created slice doesn't share underlying array with existing slice?

In case of other slice oeprations, like mySlice[x:y], new slice would share underlying array with mySlice as [this](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/8) shows.

PS: Test code:

```
var names = make([]string, 4, 10)
names1 := append(names, "Tom")
```

So in this case there is sufficient capacity available in names. Hence append must not create new underlying array.

This outputs:

```
[   ]
[    Tom]
```

Shouldn't output be same as underlying array is shared?

I am surely missing something very basic here.

Comment: I think your question is answered in the first few sentences of that the godoc link: "The append built-in function appends elements to the end of a slice. If it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements. If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated"

Comment: If append allocates a new backing array, then the returned slice has a different backing array than the argument slice.

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro is a useful introduction to the implementation of slices, which might help you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `names1` uses the same underlying array as `names`.

And no, the output should not be the same, because `names` has length 4, while  `names1` has length 5. Note, that both have capacity (10).

Here's an example, that might clarify this a little:

```
func main() {
    emptyNames := make([]string, 0, 10)
    notEmptyNames := append(emptyNames, "Jerry")
    extendedNames := emptyNames[:1] // OK, because 1 < cap(emptyNames)
    fmt.Println("emptyNames:", emptyNames)
    //emptyNames: []
    fmt.Println("notEmptyNames:", notEmptyNames)
    //notEmptyNames: [Jerry]
    fmt.Println("extendedNames:", extendedNames)
    //extendedNames: [Jerry]
}
```

Comment: I think 'make([]T, len,capacity)' is very misleading.Coming from other languages, it gives an impression that this slice can be extended upto given capacity. But this is not the case as far as I understand.

Comment: You can think of it as "initial capacity". It's optional. This form of slice creation is mostly useful when you know the target size (e.g. when copying an existing data structure). In most other cases a slice literal would be preferred (`slice := []string{}`).

Answer (score 0):

Append returns new slice struct, but underlaying array can be shared or not, depending on capacity: if the capacity is sufficient then it will share, otherwise will not.

[Slice struct](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go#L15) has length, capacity and pointer to underlaying array fields:

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

Here is some examples:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(a []int) {
    // new array allocated, returned new slice struct
    // and it is assigned to local copy of slice struct
    a = append(a, 7)

    // element changed in local copy of slice struct
    a[1] = 7
}

func bar(a *[]int) {
    // new array allocated, returned new slice struct
    // and it is assigned to the variable declared on first line of main function
    // as it is passed by reference
    *a = append(*a, 7)
}

func main() {
    // new slice, len and capacity equals number of elements
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    fmt.Printf("a[1]=%d\n", a[1])

    // array shared, will print a[1]=10
    b := a[1:3]
    b[0] = 10
    fmt.Printf("1. a[1]=%d\n", a[1])

    // new array allocated, will print a[1]=10
    b = append(b, a...)
    b[0] = 100
    fmt.Printf("2. a[1]=%d\n", a[1])

    // new array allocated, will print a[1]=10
    foo(a)
    fmt.Printf("3. a[1]=%d\n", a[1])

    // will print [1 10 3 4 5 6 7]
    bar(&a)
    fmt.Printf("4. a=%v\n", a)
}
```